# a function that only calls input function f every 50 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

- I am new to js.
- I am trying to make a function that only calls input function f  every 50 milliseconds.
- wrote the code in the fiddle using setTimeout.
- but isn't doing exactly what I wanted it to do
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing code below

https://jsfiddle.net/1pqznbgt/

```
function callSeconds(f){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("testing");
    }, 500)
}
```

Comment: Try changing setTimeout to setInterval.  Also use 50 instead of 500

Comment: "but its not executing." i mean... yes it is? click the button, then after the specified time an alert occurs. Did you mean it isn't doing exactly what you wanted it to do? It certainly is being called.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for your reply...yeah its not t isn't doing exactly what i wanted it to do...can you update in my code

Answer (score 1):

- You are looking for `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` (`setTimeout` will execute once, `setInterval` will execute at an interval)
- The 500 in your sample means 500ms rather than 50ms
- You will want to call `f` rather than your anonymous function, so:

What you are looking for is something like:

```
function callSeconds(f){
    setInterval(f, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that every time you call an alert() you are stopping execution of JavaScript and each browser can implement the alert differently . setTimeout() only executes once so if you call the function it will wait 500ms and issue an alert if you want a piece of code to operate continually you must use the setInterval() function but you still have the problem of how the browser chooses to handle the alert() function, normally an alert pauses execution of the current code, what effect that has on a timed execution function I do not know. I would try execution on something that does not pause or stop execution of the script. I also notice that in the code segment you have not invoked the parent function that would call the setTimeout function.

Answer (score -1):

You can do one of 2 things here.
First, don't use `setTimeout`.
Instead use `setInterval (f,50)`.

Or recursively call the function as so:

```
function foo (f){
    f();
    setTimeout (foo,50);
}
```